# how does the absolute value of e to the power of a complex number only maintain the real part?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

how does $\lvert e^{2+i} \rvert $ equal to $e^2$??

im really confused as to how this is possible pls help. this is my first time here so if anything looks weird then sorry :/

Comment: If $\theta$ is any real number, then $|e^{(i\theta)}|$ is automatically equal to $1$.  This is a consequence of the definition of $|e^{(i\theta)}|$, the definition of $|z|$, when $z = x + iy, ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, and the fact that for all $\theta, ~\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1.$

Comment: For all complex $z,w, ~|z \times w| = |z| \times |w|$.  Also, $e^{(2+i)} = e^2 \times e^i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}.$ So, when we take the modulus of $e^{i\theta}$ we get $\sqrt{\cos^2{\theta} + \sin^2{\theta}} = \sqrt{1} = 1.$

So, for any real $a$ and $b$ we have that $|e^{a + bi}| = |e^a|\cdot|e^{bi}|$ (by the multiplicative property of the modulus) which is in turn equal to $e^a \cdot 1.$ (by the positivity of $e^x$ and our earlier argument)

One way to think of this geometrically is that if we rewrite the number $e^{a + bi}$ as $Re^{i\theta},$ where $R = e^a, \theta = b,$ then $R$ gives the distance from the origin (the modulus) and $\theta$ gives the direction (argument) so changing $\theta$ maintains the same modulus while rotating about the origin.